# how to set text right\left to my customAndroidView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I want to create two rows of

TextView .... CustomeSwitvchView

CustomeSwitchView ... TextView

However, using this xml doesn't yield the expected order.

both rows show only the CustomeSwitchView aligned to right, with no text shown.

```
    <LinearLayout style="@style/settingsSection">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchLayoutRtl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.me.settings.SettingsSwitchView
                    style="@style/settingsSelection" android:background="@drawable/item_selector_single"
                android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchRtl" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switch_text"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/settingsSwitchRtl"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:text="My Settings1" />
      </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.me.settings.SettingsSwitchView
                    style="@style/settingsSelection" android:background="@drawable/item_selector_single"
                    android:id="@+id/settingsSwitch" />


                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switch_text"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/settingsSwitch"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:text="My Settings2" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/settingsSection">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchLayoutRtl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.me.settings.SettingsSwitchView
                    style="@style/settingsSelection" android:background="@drawable/item_selector_single"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchRtl" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switch_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/settingsSwitchRtl"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:text="My Settings1" />
      </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.me.settings.SettingsSwitchView
                    style="@style/settingsSelection" android:background="@drawable/item_selector_single"
                    android:id="@+id/settingsSwitch" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switch_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/settingsSwitch"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:text="My Settings2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/settingsSection">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchLayoutRtl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.me.settings.SettingsSwitchView
                  style="@style/settingsSelection"
                  android:background="@drawable/item_selector_single"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:paddingLeft="85dp"
                  android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchRtl" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switch_text"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:text="My Settings1" />
      </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/settingsSwitchLayoutRtl"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.me.settings.SettingsSwitchView
                    style="@style/settingsSelection" 
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingRight="85dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_selector_single"
                    android:id="@+id/settingsSwitch" />


                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switch_text"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:text="My Settings2" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: @EladBenda `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` are the key for that design

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but u can try it

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/settingsSection"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation = "vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchLayoutRtl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.me.settings.SettingsSwitchView
                    style="@style/settingsSelection" android:background="@drawable/item_selector_single"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchRtl" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switch_text"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/settingsSwitchRtl"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:text="My Settings1" />
      </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/settingsSwitchLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/settingsSwitchLayoutRtl"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.me.settings.SettingsSwitchView
                    style="@style/settingsSelection" android:background="@drawable/item_selector_single"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:id="@+id/settingsSwitch" />


                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switch_text"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/settingsSwitch"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:text="My Settings2" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```